# Primefaces: CheckBoxMenu with different colors

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

I want to show selectItems in `<p:selectCheckboxMenu>` with different color or background, how can I do this? Does anybody know about this? Thanks.

```
<p:selectCheckboxMenu id="testresultfilter"  value="#{testrunBean.selectedFilterResult}" filter="true" label="Execution Status" immediate="true"  valueChangeListener="#{testrunBean.handleResultChange}" style="vertical-align:middle;"  panelStyle="width:220px;" onchange="executeStatusOnChange();">           
   <f:selectItems value="#{testrunBean.validResults}" />                                 
</p:selectCheckboxMenu >
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, with a little help of css.

**CSS**

```
.ui-selectcheckboxmenu-panel .ui-selectcheckboxmenu-list-item:nth-child(3) {
  color: aqua;
  background: #ff00ff;
}

.ui-selectcheckboxmenu-panel .ui-selectcheckboxmenu-list-item:nth-child(2) {
  color: blue;
  background: #ffff00;
}

.ui-selectcheckboxmenu-panel .ui-selectcheckboxmenu-list-item:nth-child(1) {
  color: green;
  background: #ff0000;
}
```